# Analyze Logfile, if specified errors, exec command and alert by mail

Tags: shell, match, alert, logfile, monit

i'm not that much a coder, but for a program i run i want to have a loganalyzer (small shell script?) running that executes a command (kill process, start new process), and then send me an alert.

what's arround:
log file in /var/log/mylogfile.log
the programm writes there all kind of stuff, and i want the loganalyzer to search for patterns, lets say: "Error 33 File not found" or "premission changed" or "status changed".

i want the script to check the logfile every minute (crontab) an if one of the patterns matches for example 4 times in 1 minute, execude a command and alert me by mail.
as a workarround i want the script to check for all running process and kill all of them, so i tought maybe about using pkill -x [nameofprogramm]

so i tought about using tail -fn 0 and then grep for the pattern, but somehow i can't figure out how to check for x times if error happend, and then alert.

now i just get everytime the match happens an email.

any suggestions from you pro's out there?

already tried to use monit for that, but for some reasons monit is not that easy to handle in such a complex thing

thanks in advance

regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have any kind of rotatation on your logfile, but if you don't, I think you should really think about it if you plan to count the occurances of things :)

I think you should have a look on `awk` if you plan to investigate hard on your logs.

About your count, here is a simple example that will count the number of lines that contains "ERROR" in a file :

```
#!/bin/ksh
grep_occurence() {
        pattern=$1
        file=$2
        limit=$3
        nb_errors=$( grep ${pattern} ${file} | wc -l)
        if [ ! -f ${file} ]
        then
                echo "[ERROR] The file ${file} does not exists"
                exit 1
        fi


        if [ ${nb_errors} -gt ${limit} ]
        then
                echo "There were ${nb_errors} occurence of ${pattern} in ${file}"
                return ${nb_errors}

        fi
}

logfile=/var/log/mylogfile.log
#grep_occurence "PATTERN" "LOGFILE" "LIMIT"
grep_occurence "ERROR" "${logfile}" 5
```

Answer (score 0):

backslash, I would have commented your post but I don't have enough reputation to do so... So i'm making another "answer"

I think it will depends of your logs ...

If those logs are applicatives (jboss, weblogic, ...) I really not recommand to use the tail option. Because if the log is filled by 200 lines at a time due to a specific java error for example, and you make a tail -20n ... you'll miss many informations ...

Do you have the timestamp available in your logs? If yes you will be able to parse your logs and save only the last minutes for example.